# VBA - Search not showing multiple records in Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, search, listbox, userform

```
 Private Sub CommandButton10_Click()

'listbox column headers
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem
 For A = 1 To 7
 Me.ListBox1.List(0, A - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(1, A)
 Next A
 Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

'Populating listbox from search
 Dim i As Long
 For i = 2 To Sheet2.Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
 For j = 1 To 7
 H = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A" & 2, "G" & i), _
 Sheet2.Cells(i, j))
 If H = 1 And LCase(Sheet2.Cells(i, j)) = LCase(Me.TextBox2) Or H = 1 And _
 Sheet2.Cells(i, j) = Val(Me.TextBox2) Then
 Me.ListBox1.AddItem
 For x = 1 To 7
 Me.ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, x - 1) = Sheet2.Cells(i, x)
 Next x
 End If
 Next j
 Next i

'Count the listbox rows when populated
 With Me.ListBox1
 For x = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    TextBox3 = x
 Next x
 End With

End Sub
```

Hello all, I am in need of help please, Can anyone tell me why my code wont search for everything in the worksheet relating to a text e.g. there are 2 same items in the worksheet with different serial numbers but when i search for the item, only 1 record shows. Thanks.

Comment: What is `"A" & 2` intended to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Jeeped. "A" & 2 is to set obtain the 2nd value from column A

Comment: so `Range("A" & 2, "G" & i)` is the same as `Range("A2:G" & i)` ?

Comment: Hi Jeeped, Yes thank you, that would be the same i believe

Comment: The thing is I am getting the record I want by typing in the textbox and hitting search button. However, when I search for an item, only 1 record show instead of all of them

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include everything from Private Sub ... to End Sub?

Comment: Hey Jeeped, I have included everything now. Thanks

Comment: Which worksheet's private code sheet is this in? Is it Sheet2?

Comment: Sheet2 is the Worksheet (AssetData). This Private code is in UserForm4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change:

```
 H = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A" & 2, "G" & i), Sheet2.Cells(i, j))
```

to:

```
 H = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("A" & i, "G" & i), Sheet2.Cells(i, j))
```

so that:

- the match is being searched row by row
- following check `If H = 1 And LCase(Sheet2.Cells(i, j)) ...` isn't excluding any possible multiple occurrences of the same item (which would return H>1 if counted from row 2 downwards)

note: this way you'll miss any possible match for item having multiple occurrences in the same row

Comment: Thank you so much Display. That worked well. You saved me a lot of fustration on this one.